# Do Ember.js support model for Application route?

Tags: ember.js, model, handlebars.js

In my Ember Application Handlebars template, I need some model data to display. In Index or other routes, these types of code work but in application route they are not working. **Application Route**:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function()
 {
  return this.store.findAll('archive');
 }
});
```

Application template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
 {{#each}}
  {{title}}
 {{/each}}
</script>
```

DS.Model:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

App.Archive = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  day:   DS.attr('number')
});

App.Archive.FIXTURES = [
 {
  "id":1,
  "title": "First title",
  "day": 06
 },
 {
  "id":2,
  "title": "Second title",
  "day": 08
 }
];
```

I couldn't find out where is the prob. In Ember, can I use model for Application template?

Comment: Do you have an application controller defined somewhere that isn't an array controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes definitely, the main reason your code wouldn't be working would be if you have an application controller defined that wasn't an ArrayController.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1115/edit

Comment: I'm using `App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({})`

Comment: if you switch it to `App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({})` you should be good to go!

Comment: Now I'm getting some other probs. I'm getting `Error while processing route: index undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Actually my whole App doesn't use ember data except Application template since its data is not dynamic. Other routes models get populate using ajax json. All work well if I don't use any model for Application template.

Comment: Atlast get it working. There were some probs in my json format. Thanks for help.